# In Bootstrap 4, Glyphicons is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

Recently I have downloaded **bootstrap** 4 and I found that there ***fonts*** folder is missing and ***glyphicon is not included in css***.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap 4:

"Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default, but we have a handful of recommendations for you to choose from. While most icon sets include multiple file formats, we prefer SVG implementations for their improved accessibility and vector support."

**Preferred**

We’ve tested and used these icon sets ourselves.

- [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)
- [Iconic](https://github.com/iconic/open-iconic)
- [Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)

If you want to use Glyphicons I suggest re-downloading the package because they are no longer included in the CSS/Fonts. Above are Bootstraps recommended icon sets.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/extend/icons/

Answer (score 1):

On the Bootstrap website you can read:

> Includes over 250 glyphs in font format from the Glyphicon Halflings
>   set. Glyphicons Halflings are normally not available for free, but
>   their creator has made them available for Bootstrap free of cost. As a
>   thank you, we only ask that you include a link back to Glyphicons
>   whenever possible.

As I understand you can use these 250 glyphs free of cost restricted for Bootstrap but not limited to version 3 exclusive. So you can use them for Bootstrap 4 too BUT **glyphicons is not included in bootstrap 4**.

If you want use this *glyphicons fonts* then you have to add this in your project. To add this follow the step.

1. **[download](https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman-website/tree/a97d6b4c5b29594004e3855f1ab1222449d0c211/content/fonts) glyphicons fonts** ( *you can also collect these form bootstrap 3* )
   [image]
2. **[download](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css) glyphicons *css***.
3. Save both in your project directory.